# How to make a vector2 slowly go to a number [0]?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ship which is moving around with rigidbody velocity, and when the player has no input I want the ship to slow down to 0 and then stay at 0 until there's more input. What I have now is:

```
        if(yAxis == 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine (StopRoutine());
        }

        IEnumerator StopRoutine()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
        
        Vector2 force = rb.velocity;
        
        
        rb.velocity = (new Vector2(0.2f,0.2f)) - force;
        
    }
```

and all that does is make the ship go backward which I understand is due to it subtracting forever with no clamp, I just don't know how to make it go to 0 and STAY at 0, I also don't know how I would do it the other way too (making a vector2 which is in the negatives go to 0)

Comment: You could try something like this: `rb.velocity*=0.8;`, but from experience I can tell that most easy solutions do not work (from player perspective) and you probably will end up with some if-s there.

Comment: Perhaps `Mathf.SmoothDamp` ? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html

Comment: Actually you needn't do anything, the friction will stop the ship.

Comment: @shingo sounds like he's using velocity directly and not force.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't add force and then tweak the damping according to your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you able to do many different ways. If want a use coroutines for this sample. Try this at update method in your script...

First of all you need to declare a variable to check have any input? (I think this is wind, fuel etc.)

```
 bool isInput = true;
    IEnumerator stopRoutine(float targetX, float targetY, float valueX, float valueY, float t) //targetX and targetY your target speed values, valueX and valueY is your acceleration or deceleration values and t is waitTime for while loop...
    {
        if (isInput)
        {
            isInput = !isInput; // You've to do this because unity update function re-runs every deltaTime.
            Vector2 firstVelocity = rb.velocity;
            if (firstVelocity.x < 0f && firstVelocity.y < 0f)
            {

                while (rb.velocity.x < targetX || rb.velocity.y < targetY)
                {
                    rb.velocity += new Vector2(valueX, valueY);
                    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(t);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                while (rb.velocity.x > targetX || rb.velocity.y > targetY)
                {
                    rb.velocity -= new Vector2(valueX, valueY);
                    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't want to do it for you completely, but I want you to understand the logic in the event. Ok try this method in update()...